# Duplicate CyanogenMod's DSP Manager effect on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio

I have an Android phone with CyanogenMod installed. I use it to listen to music on the way home, and I prefer to listen to it with a slight bass boost. CyanogenMod comes with a built-in DSP Manager, which includes a 5-band equalizer, as shown here:
http://prntscr.com/88kjnz
This equalizer features 5 bands at 16, 62, 250, 1000, 4000, and 16000 HZ.

I have successfully used said DSP Manager to apply a slight bass boost by applying a 1.3dB boost to the 16HZ band, a 1.1dB boost to the 62HZ band, and a 0.8dB boost to the 250HZ band.
This can be seen here: http://prntscr.com/88kk7t

I am wondering if it is possible to duplicate this effect on Ubuntu. I've looked at PulseAudio Equalizer, but it doesn't have the bands I need. Its lowest band is 50HZ, whereas the one on my phone is 16. I've tried applying a small boost with this, but it sounds terrible, and nothing like how it sounds on my phone.

I also tried using qpaeq, which does have the bands I need (it doesn't show decibels however, perhaps I am using the wrong version?) but I can't seem to get it to apply to my sound output. Nothing sounds different when adjusting the bands. Even when I move them all the way to the top nothing is heard differently.

I am really stuck. I don't know much about audio, I only know the stuff about the bands and hertz because it's labeled :P. I also don't know much about PulseAudio. What I need is an equalizer that can boost the 16HZ, 62HZ, and 250HZ audio bands and works. Any help would be appreciated.

If there are any problems with my question or you need any more information, please let me know and I'll try to revise it as best as I can, I'm kind of a Stack Exchange noob

**EDIT**

I have figured out how to get the qpaeq equalizer working. I didn't do any of the module loading as the WebUpd8 page said, but rather just left pulseaudio how it was and started qpaeq. The equalizer says that it is set to "alsa_output.pci..." sink, and it works properly.

Comment: How's this ? It's for Rhythmbox, though. Meaning only one app. http://www.noobslab.com/2012/08/install-equalizer-for-rhythmbox-in.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use the unofficial system-wide PulseAudio equalizer:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-equalizer
```

[image]

<sub>[Source](http://m.webupd8.org/2013/10/system-wide-pulseaudio-equalizer.html?m=1)</sub>

---

Or install Pulseaudio with system-wide equalizer support in Ubuntu

1. Add a PPA and install

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/pulseaudio-eq
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install python-dbus python-qt4 python-qt4-dbus pulseaudio-utils
   ```
2. Restart pulseaudio

   ```
   pulseaudio -k 
   pulseaudio &
   ```
3. Load two modules

   ```
   pactl load-module module-equalizer-sink     
   pactl load-module module-dbus-protocol
   ```
4. Start the equalizer

   ```
   qpaeq
   ```

   And resize the window to see more bands

   [image]
5. Load the modules during the system start

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/pulse/default.pa
   ```

   And add

   ```
   ### Load the integrated pulseaudio equalizer and dbus modules 
   load-module module-equalizer-sink
   load-module module-dbus-protocol
   ```

<sub>[Source and if you have problems](http://m.webupd8.org/2013/03/install-pulseaudio-with-built-in-system.html)</sub>

Comment: As I mentioned in the OP, i tried this. It didn't have the bands i need, and when I adjusted it, it sounded distorted. Maybe I'm not doing it correctly, I'll take another look at it

Comment: Sorry, I was to fast. :\

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the answer to this, somewhat by accident. Rather than load the modules as the WebUpd8 page says, I just started qpaeq and set my output device in Sound Settings to FFT Based Equalizer. It says it's using an ALSA sink (alsa_output.pci-0000_00_14.2-analog-stereo-equalizer or something like that), and it works properly. I tried adjusting the values, and i noticed a difference.